# Questions on quantum spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I﻿ have been researching quantum physics by myself through books and videos and I can understand the property of particle “spin” but only to a limit. I understand it’s intrinsic angular momentum and orbital momentum, but I’m confused on how exactly this property can be used for information for an atomic computer. Also would superposition have any effect on spin? If I have two entangled particles I understand that I can observe one and automatically know the other is opposite spin to the first, how is spin relevant before we observe a particle? How are particles entangled if they follow superposition? I apologize if this sounds like a bunch of nonsense, I fill myself with questions with the research I encounter and found your contact information in hope for some clarification on the concept of particle spin.
Best regards, Zachary

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please only ask *one question per post* - only ask several if they are so closely related that it wouldn't make sense to split them up since they cannot reasonably be answered separately. That way, answerers that might be able to answer one question but not the others still can provide useful, complete answers to a question. Your question is essentially asking us to explain the basics of both quantum mechanics in general and quantum information in particular, which is a job for a textbook more than a physics.SE answer. Can you try to ask something more specific?